# Como eu coloco um count em uma linq que retorna uma lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Preciso fazer um `count`, para a seguinte situação. Veja na imagem abaixo, que eu tenho repetido algumas farmácias, veja os CNPJ delas(***06626253003681 e 06626253001476***). Elas estão repetidas, porque estão em datas diferentes. O que necessito é que eu faça um `count` na quantidade de farmácias e o somatório eu coloco no nó **Eucerin Hyaluron Noite 50mg**, que nesse exemplo seria 6 e ao lado de cada medicamento a quantidade 1. Acontece que na minha `LINQ` eu tenho um `ToList()` e isso não me permite dar um `Count()`. Tenho muita dificuldade para fazer isso.

Veja como está minha tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja minha linq abaixo:

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvorePdv()
{
    RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

    var _listaPdv = (
       from r in db.Ruptura
       join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
       join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
       join p in db.PDV on r.CodigoPDV equals(p.CodigoPDV)
       where r.IDMotivo != 6
       group r by new { p.Cnpj, loja = p.Descricao, a.Descricao, a.Familia, a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo, r.DataRuptura } into gr

       select new MontaArvoreAcao
       {
           CnpjDescricao = gr.Key.Cnpj + " - " + gr.Key.loja,
           Descricao = gr.Key.Descricao,
           DataRuptura = gr.Key.DataRuptura,
           Familia = gr.Key.Familia,
           IDMotivo = gr.Key.IDMotivo,
           Unidade_Negocio = gr.Key.Unidade_Negocio
       }
     ).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(r => r.Descricao);

    return _listaPdv.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Você instalou o pacote [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) que eu te falei na outra resposta? Não precisa usar esse `Count`.

Comment: ja tentou adicionar uma propriedade em MontaArvoreAcao e associar o valor gr.Count?

Comment: Instalei o MoreLinq. Como eu faço agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi assim. Criei uma campo na minha Model MontaArvoreAcao, chamado de Somatorio. Aí no linq eu fiz:

Somatorio = gr.Count()

Minha linq:

```
var _listaPdv = (
                                   from r in db.Ruptura
                                   join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                   join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                                   join p in db.PDV on r.CodigoPDV equals(p.CodigoPDV)
                                   where r.IDMotivo != 6
                                   group r by new { p.Cnpj, loja = p.Descricao, a.Descricao, a.Familia, a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo, r.DataRuptura } into gr

                                   select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                   {
                                       CnpjDescricao = gr.Key.Cnpj + " - " + gr.Key.loja,
                                       Descricao = gr.Key.Descricao,
                                       DataRuptura = gr.Key.DataRuptura,
                                       Familia = gr.Key.Familia,
                                       IDMotivo = gr.Key.IDMotivo,
                                       Unidade_Negocio = gr.Key.Unidade_Negocio,
                                       Somatorio = gr.Count()
                                   }
                                 ).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(r => r.Descricao);
```

E minha chamada na View:

```
<ul>
                                                                            @foreach (var pdv in (List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>) ViewData["ListaPdv"])
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (@pdv.Descricao == @prod.Descricao && @pdv.IDMotivo == @item.IDMotivo)
                                                                               {
                                                                                        <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                                                            @pdv.CnpjDescricao (@pdv.Somatorio)

                                                                                            </li>
                                                                            }
                                                                            }
                                                                        </ul>
```